# What is wrong with my approach for CLRS 5.4-6 : Given n balls and n bins,find expected number of empty bins?

Tags: probability, expected-value, balls-in-bins

I am trying to find expected number of empty bins after n balls are tossed into n bins. And each toss is  independent and equally likely to end up in any bin. Below is my approach.

My indicator variable is 
$X_i$ : i bins are empty
$$ Pr[X_i]=  \frac{\binom{n}{n-i} * n^\left(n-i\right)}{n^n}$$
And excepted number of empty bins is :

$$
\sum_{i=1}^\left(n-1\right) i*Pr[X_i]
$$

After simplifying the above equation I get:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\left(n-1\right) \frac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(i-1\right)!*\left(n-i\right)!*n^\left(i-1\right)}
$$
But in the solution that I found on the web, the indicator variable is : Let Xi be the event that all the balls fall in bins, other than the ith. And then expected number of empty bins is :

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n
$$

But according to me the the indicator variable chosen above is wrong. As they are adding the probabilities that ith bin is empty.So at a time only one bin is considered empty. Whereas there can be more than one bin empty at a time.
Is there something wrong with my understanding of the above problem?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong in the solution you have found on the web. It's summing over $i$ but there is no $i$ term?

Comment: The way it is done in the book is correct, by linearity of expectation.  You method would also be correct if your computation of $\Pr(X_i)$ were correct, but it isn't.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan No, it's right.  The answer is $n\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web solution is correct; it uses [linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/).  Suppose we label the boxes $1$ through $n$, and we determine $X_1$, the expected number of boxes numbered $1$ that are empty.  Since there is obviously only one box numbered $1$, this value is equal to the probability that that one box is empty:

$$
E(X_1) = P(\text{box $1$ is empty}) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n
$$

By symmetry, we have $E(X_1) = E(X_2) = \cdots = E(X_n)$, and then by linearity of expectation, the expected number of boxes that are empty is

\begin{align}
E(X) & = E(X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_k) \\
     & = E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots+E(X_n) \\
     & = nE(X_1) \\
     & = \frac{(n-1)^n}{n^{n-1}}
\end{align}

---

You can also proceed the way you set out.  However, in the expression you give for the probability that *exactly* $k$ boxes are empty, the numerator $\binom{n}{k} n^{n-k}$ does not, unfortunately, count only those cases; it also includes cases where more than $k$ boxes are empty, too (and overcounts them, to boot).

The correct expression is not trivial; it is

$$
\frac{n!}{k!} S(n, n-k)
$$

where $S(\cdot, \cdot)$ are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).  See [this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A219859) for more details on the particular count.  It is also written

$$
\frac{n!}{k!} \left\{ n \atop n-k \right\}
$$

All in all, you're better off using linearity of expectation. :-)

Comment: I understood the problem of over counting in my solution. But is not over counting happening in this solution also. As according to X1, box 1 must be empty. According to the equation, we are calculating that at least box 1 is empty. Other boxes can also be empty?

Comment: @VK: Yes.  The difference is that we regard the probability that box $1$ as empty as also the expected number of box $1$ that is empty.  They are equal to the same value, but conceptually, the two are different things.  (For instance, the probability that two boxes are both empty is not equal to the expected number of them that are empty.)  Probability is not linear (in general, depending on what the probability is of), but expectation is, and we take advantage of that.

Comment: My point was that when we are counting the expected number of times box 1 is empty we  are also counting , when box 2 is also empty. Same thing will be counted when we count for box 2. It will also count the case when box 1 is empty along with box 2. So same arrangement is being counted more than once.

Comment: @VK: You're not incorrect, but that point doesn't have any bearing on that approach.  Let's take a simpler case as an example.  Suppose that we flip a coin twice, and we want to know the average number of heads that come up.  We find the probability that the first coin comes up heads, which is $1/2$.  Some of the time the first coin comes up heads, the second coin also comes up heads, but we don't care about that.  We interpret the probability of the first coin coming up heads as the *expected number of first coins that come up heads*.

Comment: (cont'd) By a similar line of reasoning, the expected number of second coins that come up heads is also $1/2$, and then we add them together to get $1$, the expected number of coins that come up heads.  That turns out to be correct.  We could also have computed the probability that *exactly* one head comes up ($1/2$) and multiply that by $1$, then add the probability that *exactly* two heads come up ($1/4$) multiplied by $2$, yielding $1/2 + 1/2 = 1$.

Comment: What is in the original question you posted is more akin to multiplying the probability that *at least* one head comes up ($3/4$) multiplied by $1$ and adding the probability that at least two heads come up ($1/4$) multiplied by $2$, yielding $3/4 + 1/2 = 5/4$.  It isn't *exactly* the same, to be sure, but the type of error is comparable.

Comment: So, as per the scenario in the above comment. If we subtract at least one head to at least two heads. Then we will get expected value of exactly 2 heads?

Comment: @VK: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.  The probability of at least one head is $3/4$.  The probability of at least two heads is $1/4$.  If you subtract the latter *from* the former, you get the probability of exactly one head, which is $3/4 - 1/4 = 1/2$.

Comment: Its ok, I got the answer.